# 08S01 FreeTDS SQL Server Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, freetds, debian-buster

For some reason I'm not able to establish a connection to MSSQL Server with FreeTDS in a `python:3.7-slim-buster` (debian) docker image.

### Code

Also available on [github](https://github.com/Loknar/docker-freedts-mssqlserver-connection-issue) ..

`Dockerfile`

```sh
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

# install free-tds used for MSSQL connections
RUN sed -i "s#deb http://security.debian.org/debian-securitystretch/updates main#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main#g" /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y g++
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
RUN apt-get install -y freetds-dev
RUN apt-get install -y freetds-bin
RUN apt-get install -y tdsodbc

# create a freetds odbc driver path
# required so python scripts can reference {FreeTDS} in their pypyodbc connections
RUN echo "[FreeTDS]" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "Description=FreeTDS Driver" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini
RUN echo "Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini

RUN apt-get clean

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --default-timeout=2000 --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY example.py .

# set entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT python example.py
```

`example.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import platform

import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc


def connect():
    driver = '{FreeTDS}' if platform.system() != 'Windows' else '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    creds = {  # dummy credentials
        'server': 'mssqlserver.mydomain.com',
        'port': '1443',
        'database': 'my_database_name',
        'username': 'my_username',
        'password': 'my_password'
    }
    return pypyodbc.connect(
        (
            'DRIVER={driver};'
            'SERVER={server};'
            'PORT={port};'
            'DATABASE={database};'
            'UID={username};'
            'PWD={password};'
            'TDS_Version={tds_version};'
        ).format(
            driver=driver,
            server=creds['server'],
            port=creds['port'],
            database=creds['database'],
            username=creds['username'],
            password=creds['password'],
            tds_version='7.2'
        )
    )


def dummy_query(conn):
    sql_query = '''SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('Hello world'),('Hello world')) t1 (col1) WHERE 1=1'''
    return pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = connect()
    data = dummy_query(conn)
    print(data)
```

`requirements.txt`

```
pandas==0.25.1
pypyodbc>=1.3.4
```

### When running on Windows

works fine

`python example.py`

```
          col1
0  Hello world
1  Hello world
```

### When using docker

doesn't work, fails with a `pypyodbc.DatabaseError` ..

#### Building docker image

`docker build . -t freetds_issue`

#### Running docker image

`docker run freetds_issue`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 51, in <module>
    conn = connect()
  File "example.py", line 40, in connect
    tds_version='7.2'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 2454, in __init__
    self.connect(connectString, autocommit, ansi, timeout, unicode_results, readonly)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 2507, in connect
    check_success(self, ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 1009, in check_success
    ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pypyodbc.py", line 987, in ctrl_err
    raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist')
```

#### Some output from within docker

`docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" freetds_issue`

Output of `tsql -C`:

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v1.00.104
             freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
                            OpenSSL: no
                             GnuTLS: yes
                               MARS: no
```

Output of `tsql -LH {server_ip}`:

```
     ServerName SERVERNAME
   InstanceName MSSQLSERVER
    IsClustered No
        Version 14.0.1000.169
            tcp 1433
```

strangely, using `tsql` CLI to connect seems to work ..

`tsql -S mssqlserver.mydomain.com -U my_username`

```
Password:
locale is "C.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1> exit
```

Comment: Can you verify that `driver` is `{FreeTDS}` under the Linux build? Can you also try connecting with `isql -v -k` to test the `unixODBC` layer of the connection? https://gerardnico.com/odbc/unix/isql

Comment: Not fully sure how to verify that. Regarding `isql -v -k`, I needed to add `RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc` to the Dockerfile to have isql at my disposal, output I get is `[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified`
`[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect`

Comment: For now I'm using the Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server for Linux provided by Microsoft to get things working, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 ... however, I noticed the resulting docker image is considerably larger, so I'm still interested in finding out how to get FreeTDS working ...

Comment: I have also run into exact same issue. In my case I am using python 3.9. Did you find any solution about it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local container and a local SQL Server instance (no volume), you may have to user the value `host.docker.internal` for the database server name when running the docker image.

It is also useful to look Seeya Xi-MSFT recomendations in the Microsoft post [unable to connect ms sql server from python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/799994/unable-to-connect-ms-sql-server-from-python)